# MySQL Create Table from Query

Tags: mysql, view

I have a large table with what are essentially log entries. For most of my queries, I need a table with the most recent entries, so I created a 'view' from the following query:

```
SELECT t1.store_id, t1.code_id, t1.working, t1.expiration, t1.details, t1.price
    FROM code_stores t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN code_stores t2
    ON (t1.store_id = t2.store_id AND t1.code_id = t2.code_id AND t1.id < t2.id)
    WHERE t2.store_id IS NULL
```

Then I use this 'view' in my query. Unfortunately this is leading to slow queries, so I'd like to cache the results of this view somehow. Since this view will only change a few times a day (when I can run a query to update the cache table), I would like to create a temporary table that stores the results of this view, and update this throughout the day.

How do I go about doing this? I read about materialized views, but it appears that they don't work with mysql. More help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you add indexes?

Comment: Are you referring to adding indexes to specific columns? I've gone through and added them anywhere a 'WHERE' or 'JOIN ON' is used, and performance is still very poor (1 second per query). I've tried using 'EXPLAIN', but I've been pulling my hair out for quite some time trying to figure this out. My thought was caching this view might improve performance.

Comment: It appears that my problem is the number of results from the query. The query is outputting >1000 rows. If I apply a LIMIT 20, it reduces the query time to 13ms. I think I just need to come up with a better results page for this, that doesn't involve displaying 1000 rows.

Comment: Despite this, I'd still like to know how to create a temporary table, as code stores will be growing from ~1M rows to 100M rows, and I'd imagine performance will only get worse.

Answer (score 0):

With the idea of using a temporary table, I suggest using trigger so that temporary table is updated each time the code_store table changes.

Comment: I could use triggers, or I could force an update of the temporary table after my backend finishes an update to the full table. Either way though, I'm still not sure how to create a temporary table like this that is based on a query.